# Is seq_len(x) always faster than 1:x in R? Is one more preferred than the other?

Tags: r

This question is self-explanatory. But there must be a reason for having multiple functions in R that do the same thing.

Within loops, is one of `seq_len()` or `:` more preferred in terms of speed?

Documentation doesn't tell the full story in my view.

Comment: You can check it out yourself using `microbenchmark::microbenchmark()`.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~drh20/astrostatistics/PennState2006/html/base/html/seq.html), `a:b` is equivalent to `seq(from=a, to=b)`.  Not sure about `seq_len`.

Comment: Compare their output with x <- 0. seq_len is safer for some purposes.

Comment: @Phil Thanks. Using microbenchmark(), seq_len is slightly slower for a sequence of 1000 consecutive elements in [1: 1000].

Comment: @Roland In what instances can seq_len be considered "safer"?

Comment: @JarrettPhillips A common gotcha is `for (i in 1:n)` where `i` can become zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that `seq_len(x)` and `:` are somewhat more limited than `seq()`:

- `seq_len(b)` generates an `integer` sequence from 1 to `b`
- `a:b` generates a `numeric` sequence from `a` to `b` with spacing 1 (`a` and `b` need not be `integer` (and so the result need not be an `integer` sequence)
- `seq(a, b, c)` generates a `numeric` sequence from `a` to `b` with step length `c`. `a`, `b`, `c` can be `numeric` or `integer` or mixed.

If `seq_len` and `:` are appropriate for you, they should be favored over `seq()` since they are/call primitives (fast C functions).

As proposed in the comments to your question this can be seen from a benchmark:

```
bench::mark(
 ":" = 1:1e5,
 "seq" = seq(1, 1e5),
 "seq_len" = seq_len(1e5)
)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  expression      min   median `itr/sec`
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl>
1 :             132ns    227ns  2677132.
2 seq          4.15µs   4.71µs   197204.
3 seq_len       113ns    170ns  2236432.
```

It seems that `seq_len()` is somewhat faster than `:`.

**N.B.**

Some of these functions have some quirks to be aware of:

E.g.

```
x <- numeric(0)
y <- length(x)
```

you get

```
1:y
[1] 1 0
```

but

```
seq_len(y)
integer(0)
```

so the former can be an issue when dealing with arrays.

Comment: You're right, made some edits!